# How to reference a page that contains parenthesis in SPARQL

Tags: python, sparql

I am trying to lookup information regarding someone on Dbpedia but their name contains parenthesis in this case ending with _(musician) which leads to an error.

```
SELECT ?birthPlace
WHERE {
  dbpedia:Tom_Johnston_(musician) dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace   
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parentheses aren't legal in prefixed names, but you can just use the full URI instead:

```
SELECT ?birthPlace
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tom_Johnston_(musician)> dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace   
}
```

It's also possible to [escape them using `\`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynIRI):

> SPARQL local names also allow the non-alphanumeric characters allowed in IRIs via backslash character escapes (e.g. ns:id\=123).

```
SELECT ?birthPlace
WHERE {
    dbpedia:Tom_Johnston_\(musician\) dbpprop:birthPlace ?birthPlace   
}
```